# when i exit from node js, i just cant give command in my terminal

Tags: node.js, terminal

I am testing the simplest node js like:
node express_serer.js
to list my 8080port
this code runs fine and in y terminal it says:
Example app listening on port 8080!
I solved this question, just simply press contrl c then I can get back to command mode

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/97261/ending-a-process-in-unix-instead-of-interrupting-it

Comment: Provide some more details, and write your question as a formal sentence; no slangs like "_y terminal_" here, please. Also, refer to the site @brandonscript has posted; your answer may be there.

Comment: When you run an express app it continues to run - you've booted up a server. You can't use that terminal to run other commands while it's running Express. You can wrap express in other commands (checkout pm2) or open another terminal to run other commands.

Answer (score 1):

You have to stop running Node process to come back to terminal.
Try Ctrl+C

If you want to keep Node running you can use Ctrl+Z the send process to background. Then use `fg` command to return to Node process console

Third option, open another window